# Exception thrown when starting StreamWriter

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, streamwriter

Every 24 hours, my code auto-generates a .csv-file, writes it temporarily to an Azure directory, and finally deletes it after operating on it.

It succeeds, but from the logs I can see, that an exception is thrown.

**Exception:**

> "The process cannot access the file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\myFile.csv'
> because it is being used by another process."

The log points to these two lines of code, where I simply specify the directory and file-name and then start a StreamWriter:

```cs
string filePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myFile.csv"; //Specify where to create csv on hosted Azure server (not locally)
using (var w = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, new UTF8Encoding(false))) //Exception is thrown here
{
    //more code
}
```

I am very confused, how the two above lines can result in that exception, especially since the file is always deleted after upload.

Comment: 2 processes are accessing the same file, its as simple as that

Comment: You need to trust me when I tell you this, there ***is*** more than one process trying to access (or write) to the file at once (even if you think it is a new file). Note that azure services are scalable, especially functions and especially functions on consumption plans... Edit, oh your comment has disappeared

Comment: @TheGeneral I did a more digging into the logs after reading your comment, and I can see, that the process of uploading/deleting files is executed **two** times instead of one. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction! You are welcome to provide an official answer to this post.

Comment: :) no problems, good luck

Comment: @TheGeneral - Please post your comments as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri It is all good, I will post it as an answer myself otherwise, just giving him/her a chance to do it before, since they were the one who should be credited for an answer. I am keeping an eye on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular case, the problem was that the `StreamWriter` code was executed **twice**, instead of the intended *once*. Thanks to user TheGeneral for guiding me in the right direction in the comments.